# How do I align / anchor Html with the edges of available area?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a bit of a styling problem in that I want my form elements to take up to available size when using the bootstrap grid system. In the code example here

```
<div>
<h1>Data Entry Form</h1>
<div class="row form">        
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="Callsign">Callsign: VH-</label>
                <input name="Callsign" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="acType">Type:</label>
                <input name="acType" />
            </div>        
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                <label for="Description">Description:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="Description"></textarea>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is rendered like this

[image]

However I need it rendered like this
[image]

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **bootrap Class form-control**

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1>Data Entry Form</h1>
<div class="row form">        
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
            <label for="Callsign">Callsign: VH-</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="Callsign" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
            <label for="acType">Type:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="acType" />
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <label for="Description">Description:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-8">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="Description"></textarea>
        </div>                
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edited**:
First you need to style the text-area with a width of 100%. There is a media query which is making the text-area go to a new line. If you can not remove that query you can add a new one to avoid the behaviour:

```
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 769px) {
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 769px) {
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <h1>Data Entry Form</h1>
  <div class="row form">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <label for="Callsign">Callsign: VH-</label>
          <input name="Callsign" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <label for="acType">Type:</label>
          <input name="acType" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
          <label for="Description">Description:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-10">
          <textarea name="Description"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```